# The fastest way for relinking a directory

Tags: linux, performance, mount, symbolic-link, bind

I use a Gentoo Linux, and I'm currently moving my `/usr/portage` (portage's database, containing thousands of small ebuild files), `/var/tmp/portage` (portage's compiling directory), and `/var/tmp/ccache` (compiler cache directory) to reiserfs. These directories are performance sensitive and thousands of small files are accessed and written when portage is calculating package dependencies and compiling packages.

What is the fastest way of redirecting the directories into the new filesystem? Is there a huge performance loss from using a symlink since the system parse a symlink as a text? Is mount bind going to be better?

Comment: I cannot help you with this, but I'm wondering, is reiserfs still relevant?

Comment: Good point fideli.  I think XFS or EXT4 would be a better option.

Comment: I have heard that using tar to back up then untar to restore is quicker and safer than using cp -R.  Can anyone verify that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Mount --bind` should be faster then symbolic link.

If you `mount -B /mnt/portage /usr/portage` reading `/usr/portage` will give you i-node of `/mnt/portage` and it should work as fast as normal directory.

Resolving symbolic link speed will depend on number of components in the linked path, so for `/usr/portage` linked to `/mnt/portage` it will be three additional i-node reads and two directory searches.

I doubt you will notice any difference between these methods, unless you are really using these file systems a lot.

Comment: Doesn't mount --bind just make the mount point appear in two places but the files will still be written on the old filesystem, not the new?

Comment: Files will be written to the new filesystem unless some process opened them from the old one before mount. In that case process needs to be restarted.